# Conversion of arbitrary range to luma

Tags: image-processing, data-visualization, rgb

I have 2d matrix of values in range `<-a, b>`. I would like to visualize this image by grayscale image. How I should process my data to visualize it correctly?

As far as I know human eye has logarithmic scale, so my transformation should be logarithmic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your values to the luma in a perceptually uniform color space, for example CIE Lab or Luv. Then convert from that to RGB for display.

These are available in the colormath module, for example.

If your input value is in x

```
L = 100*(x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin) # L is 0-100
a, b = 0, 0 # neutral values

from colormath.color_objects import LabColor, RGBColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color

lab = LabColor(L, a, b)
rgb = convert_color(lab, RGBColor)
# display rgb
```

Matplotlib has a lot of info about this in the section on colormaps:. https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html